"Universality" of Carnot cycles
In his answer to the discussion "Historical view of the second law of thermodynamics as a complete differential" (https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/823281)
@hyportnex wrote that:

Contrary to what one may generalize mistakenly from the usual
elementary thermodynamics courses regarding ideal gasses, how and what
part of the absorbed thermal energy can be used to produce work does
not depend on these axioms directly but rather on the particular
constitutive relationships defining the body and the processes they go
through; to illustrate the issue here is a famous example problem I.6,
p347 and Sommerfeld's solution p359 in Sommerfeld: Thermodynamics and Statistical Mechanics
"I.6. Imagine a Carnot cycle with water as the working substance operating
between 2C and 6C so that at 6C there is isothermal expansion and
isothermal compression at 2C. It is seen that heat is added during
both processes, if the pressure is low enough, and so heat is
converted completely into work in violation of the second law. How is
it possible to resolve this contradiction?"

Sommerfeld's problem and its offered solution seem to prove that for water Carnot cycles between the two given temperatures may not exist (i.e. may not be physically realizable), and  that is due to the physical behaviour of the substance used in that temperature range (in that specific case it was the "anomalous" density of the water in the range 0-4 °C).
Sommerfeld's example brings up two closely related questions:

Is the Carnot cycle and principle really universal in the sense that
hold for all material bodies and between any two positive absolute
temperatures or there are bodies, such as water around $4C$ are
excluded?

If water in its anomalous region can have a Carnot cycle then in what form?



"The Sommerfeld problem mentioned from @hyportnex seems to prove that Carnot cycles between two given temperatures may not exist (i.e. may not be physically realizable)". Who said a Carnot cycle is "physically realizable"?  It is generally acknowledged to be an idealization only for the purpose of establishing an upper limit to the efficiency of a heat engine cycle.

Thank @BobD. It is clear that Carnot cycles are idealizations (at least since they are reversible processes).  I was just trying to fully understand the sense of the statement "how and what part of the thermal energy usable to produce work does not depend on the axioms". But maybe I am overquestioning

It would be helpful if you could present the axioms here or provide a link to where they are accessible

Hi BobD the details (links and axioms) you are looking for are in the answer from hyportnex below and subsequent comments

The Carnot cycle is realizable. In Sommerfeld's answer entropy is expressed as function of $T,v$ but it is easier to see what is happening with independent variables $T,p$, in which case $$Tds=c_pdT-\beta Tvdp \tag{1}$$ where $\beta = \frac{1}{v}\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial T}\right)_p$ denotes the coefficient of isobaric thermal expansion.
At 1bar pressure the density of water is maximum at 4C, that is $\beta(T=4C, p=1b) = 0$. If $\beta(T=4C) = 0$ for all $p$ of interest, as Sommerfeld assumed in his problem and as it is indeed true approximately for a wide range of $p$, then $ds=\frac {c_p}{T}dT$ at $T=4C$ and also at that temperature the isentropic $ds=0$ and the isothermal $dT=0$ surfaces (curves) are tangential and coincide. If they do coincide then the isentropics assumed in the problem setup cannot exist.
This problem has vexed some physicists; Thomsen and Hartka made a detailed analysis using the best available measured data, see Thomsen & Hartka: "Strange Carnot Cycles; Thermodynamics of a System with a Density Extremum," Am. J. Phys. 30, 26–33 (1962), https://doi.org/10.1119/1.1941890
and here I will briefly give the highlights of their results.
(I wanted to mention this paper in my prior post but by the time I found the archive Sommerfeld reference I forgot all about it; sorry.)
They took the interpolated data of $v(T,p)$ and $c_p(T,p)$ integrated it  to get $s(T,p)$ with the other thermodynamic potentials to test the interpolation accuracy. It showed that in fact the isentropic does not coincide with the isothermal because the density peak actually depends on the pressure slightly, very slightly, but slightly. This is shown in Fig 1 where the specific volume is plotted against temperature at various pressures.

Next is Fig 3 showing the isentropic curves, notice that they have a nonmonotonic parabolic shape. The straight line represents the $\beta=0$ peak density points.

The Fig 5 below shows the kind of Carnot cycles one can form with the isentropics of Fig 3.


Fig 5(a) is the shape of the normal Carnot cycle that can be found in
any text book.
Fig 5(b) is the shape of the Carnot cycle that the    Sommerfeld
problem can have.

To 5(b) corresponds the $p,v$ diagram of Fig 7 showing that the two isentropics of the Carnot Cycle do cross on the $p,v$ plot creating much confusion and also showing the problem inherent in the Caratheodory approach to thermostatics that attempts to derive the thermal interaction from mechanics using adiabatic processes with energy conservation.

Returning now to Fig 5(b), $T_2>T_1$ are the temperatures of the isothermal interaction, that is, $T_2=6C, T_1=2C$. In both isothermal stages the pressure decreases representing volumetric expansions. Even more surprising is that while at $T_2$ heat (entropy) is absorbed and the water expands, at $T_1$ the water still expands but the body now rejects the same amount of entropy at $T_1$ as it has absorbed at $T_2$. So it is indeed an honest Carnot cycle consisting of isothermal-isentropic-isothermal-isentropic stages but unlike the "normal" CC in which there is high temperature isothermal expansion and a low temperature isothermal compression, here both isothermal stages are expansive.

Many thanks @hyportnex. I had been struggling a bit with the Sommerfeld problem but wasn't able to get/sketch the plots in both T-V or P-V spaces. I will study your post as well as the reference thomsen hartka to better understand. An apparently strange feature (among the others you have highlighted)  is the "crossing" of the CC curve in the P-V plane which makes the CCa double CC actually.

The reason why I detailed T&H here at such lengths was because in the original question to which you were referring the convertibility of heat into work was explicitly brought up. Sommerfeld's problem is an example where that kind of verbiage is completely confusing.  In past several answers, you can search for them here, I discussed how to avoid this confusing language using Bronsted's (Carnot, Le Chatelier, Gouy, etc.) thermodynamics in which thermal work always and everywhere is not "heat" but entropy moved from a higher to a lower temperature, or vice versa.

Got the time to fully read the Thomsen Hartka paper; very interesting. Their conclusions are nicely synthetized in your answer above.  No paradox is present since the equivalence between isothermal and isenthropic curves at 4 °C just holds at a specific pressure and not within a finite (small) range of pressures at that temperature. So isenthropic curves can "cross" the 4 °C point and "join" the two isothermals at 2°C and 6 °C .

It is curious (but necessary to the purpose) that isenthropic curves need to reach lower temperatures than the lowest temperature of the Carnot Cycle. Carnot Cycles can thus be set up and behave normally apart from the fact that isothermal at low T needs to be performed in expansion (if we want W>0) to adapt to the water "anomalous behaviour" regime.

I have not experimented numerically by the analytic formula for the S(T,P) stated in the paper, but I trust that isenthropic curves in a CC in the T-P plane cannot cross. Should they cross, the CC could again perform the two isothermals in two opposite directions, i.e. expansion and compression, as with the normal CCs.

To make you feel better about thinking first that Carnot (and Bronsted) might have been wrong here is Truesdell writing in his book "Rational Thermodynamics", page 54, while speaking of Problem I.6: "Thus he would have been unable to demonstrate the qualitative properties of the adiabats of water. CARATHEODORY seems to have had no acquaintance with the specific problems thermodynamics is designed to handle. Here in alleviation of his failure we may notice that his somewhat older friend and later colleague, the physicist SOMMERFELD, fared no better when he faced water, ...

....and his editors, eminent physicists of a more recent stamp, published a flagrant error regarding it. From the standpoint of KELVIN the matter is simple, and KELVIN (1854) was the first to state that $\Lambda_v$  < 0$ in the range of anomalous behavior." The editor in the quote was his friend Kestin who wrote an otherwise amazingly good book titled "A COURSE IN THERMODYNAMICS."

Lots of books to read. My personal list: 1- fermi (read), 2- pippard (almost completed) 3- reiss (read some parts) 4- zemansky 5- callen 6-adkins 7- buchdahl 8- wilson 9- kestin 10- finn then 11- truesdell. 4 to 11 all to read. The list does not include statistical mechanics books (huang, ma, gallavotti and kittel first)

There are two important books missing from your list which, except for Finn's and Wilson's, I have studied over the years, too. Looking back now with nostalgia, those missing to me are the most important the way presently I understand this whole business: Bronsted:PRINCIPLES AND PROBLEMS IN ENERGETICS, Interscience, 1955 and Bridgman: THE THERMODYNAMICS OF ELECTRICAL PHENOMENA IN METALS, 1934, especially Bronsted's work was/is a revelation....

Had Sommerfeld grown up on Bronsted and not on Clausius he would have never made that ice-cold mistake...
